# javascript setInterval() Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, setinterval

i'm not that good in JavaScript if you can halp me..i have a slide, what i have to do is to add a bottom to either make it autoplay or stop it. when i put just an Alert inside the function it works but when i put the interval code it won't. here is my [codepen link](https://codepen.io/ZinebS/pen/EXLzpz)

here is my slide code:

```
<div class="Dash_map_wrapSlider" id="Dash_map_wrapSlider">  
            <div style="border: 1px solid red;width: 100%;">
                <input id="Dash_map_sumSlideSite" class="clsDashMap_sumSlideInput" type="radio" name="slides" checked>
                <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Site " style="float: left;width: 50%;border: 2px solid yellow;">
                    <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle">SITE</div>
                    <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
                        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
                            <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Etat</div>
                            <div class="green led">OK</div>
                            <div class="red led">KO</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
                            <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">AlarmesSite</div>
                            <canvas id="pieChartAlm" ></canvas>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
                            <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">TicketsSite</div>
                            <canvas id="pieChartTkt" ></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContent">put here content</div>
                </div>

                <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Alarme" style="float: left;width: 50%; border: 2px solid green;">
                    <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle" style="left:0;">ALARME</div>
                    <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
                        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
                            <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Etat</div>
                            <div class="green led">OK</div>
                            <div class="red led">KO</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
                            <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">ALARME1Alm</div>
                            <canvas id="pieChartAlm" ></canvas>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
                            <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Tickets1Alm</div>
                            <canvas id="pieChartTkt" ></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContent">put here content</div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="border: 1px solid red;">
                <input id="Dash_map_sumSlideAlarme" class="clsDashMap_sumSlideInput" type="radio" name="slides" checked>            
                <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Site " style="width: 50%;border: 2px solid black;">
                    <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle">TECHNICIEN</div>
                    <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
                        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
                            <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Etat</div>
                            <div class="green led">OK</div>
                            <div class="red led">KO</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
                            <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Alarmes2Tech</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
                            <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Tickets2Tech</div>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContent">put here content</div>
                </div>
                    <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Alarme" style="width: 50%;border: 2px solid darkturquoise;">
                    <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle" style="position: initial;">ACTION</div>
                    <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
                        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
                            <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Etat</div>
                            <div class="green led">OK</div>
                            <div class="red led">KO</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
                            <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">alarme3Act</div>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
                            <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Tickets3Act</div>                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContent">put here content</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
            <div class="Dash_map_wrapSliderchoise">
                <label for="Dash_map_sumSlideSite">Site / Alarme</label>
                <label for="Dash_map_sumSlideAlarme">Technicien / Action</label>
      <span id="autoplay" style="color:#fff;">Autoplay</span>
            </div>
```

My JS code :

```
function playSlide() {
        console.log('heeey');
        var elementSlide = document.getElementById('autoplay');
        elementSlide.onclick = function(){
            //alert('hey beauty !');
            setInterval(function(){
                $('#autoplay');
            }, 3000);
        };
    }
```

Thank you !

Comment: What do you want to autoplay? any effect or what? because you just add `$("#autoplay")` in `setInterval`

Comment: What do you want to do with this part of code inside the setInterval : '$('#autoplay');' ?

Comment: @zinebs i dont see a slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your playSlide method like this. This will iterate through the radio buttons and check the next every 3 seconds.

```js
var nextSlide = 0;
var slideTimer = null;
function playSlide() {
    var elementSlide = document.getElementById('autoplay');
    
    elementSlide.onclick = function() {
        var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#Dash_map_wrapSlider input[id^="Dash"]');
        
        if (!slideTimer) {
            elementSlide.innerHTML = "Stop";
            slideTimer = setInterval(function() {
                if (slides.length <= nextSlide) 
                    nextSlide = 0;

                console.log('showing slide ' + nextSlide);
                slides.forEach(function (slide, index) {
                    slide.checked = index === nextSlide;
                });

                nextSlide++;
            }, 3000);
        } else {
            elementSlide.innerHTML = "Start";
            clearInterval(slideTimer);
            slideTimer = null;
        }
    };
}

playSlide();
```

```css
.Dash_map_wrapSlider {
 position: absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 width: calc(100% - 3rem);
 bottom: calc(-80% + 10rem);
 left: 3rem;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid;
 transition: 0.5s;
 z-index: 1;
}
.Dash_map_wrapSlider:hover{
 bottom: 0rem;
 transition: 0.5s;
}
.Dash_map_wrapSliderchoise {
 background: #3E474F;
 box-shadow: 0 .5em 1em #111;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 900;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2rem;
 line-height: 2rem;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.Dash_map_sumSlide {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 z-index: 10;
 background-color: #fff;
 transition: left 0s .75s;
}
.clsDashMap_sumSlideInput {
 display: none;
 height: 11rem;
}
.clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle {
 position : absolute;
 top:0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2rem;
 left: inherit;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #73b9ff;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.20rem;
}
.clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle {
 /*padding: 10%;*/
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #666;
}
.clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary {
 position : absolute;
 top: 2rem;
 width: 100%;
 height: 16rem;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: aliceblue;
 text-align: center;
}
.clsDashMap_sumSlideContent {
 position: absolute;
 top: 20rem;
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 color: #000000;
 /* text-align: center; */
}
[id^="Dash"]:checked + .Dash_map_sumSlide {
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 transition: left .65s ease-out;
}
[id^="Dash"]:checked + .Dash_map_sumSlide + .Dash_map_sumSlide { left: 50%; transition-delay: 0.25s; }

.Dash_map_wrapSliderchoise label {
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 2rem;
 font-size: 0.75rem;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 0 1em;
 
}
/*Style leds*/
.clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox {
 margin: auto;
 float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* .clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox1Title { */
     /* position: absolute; */
    /* top: -1rem; */
    /* left: 0.3rem; */
/* } */
.led {
 border-radius: 5rem;
 width: 2rem;
 height: 2rem;
 line-height: 2rem;
}
.green {
     background-color: #36d900;
}
.red {
     background-color: #E74C3C;
}
#pieChartAlm, #pieChartTkt {
 margin: auto;
 width: 86%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Dash_map_wrapSlider" id="Dash_map_wrapSlider">
     
     
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;width: 100%;">
     <input id="Dash_map_sumSlideSite" class="clsDashMap_sumSlideInput" type="radio" name="slides" checked>
     <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Site " style="float: left;width: 50%;border: 2px solid yellow;">
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle">SITE</div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Etat</div>
        <div class="green led">OK</div>
        <div class="red led">KO</div>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">AlarmesSite</div>
        <canvas id="pieChartAlm" ></canvas>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">TicketsSite</div>
        <canvas id="pieChartTkt" ></canvas>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContent">put here content</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Alarme" style="float: left;width: 50%; border: 2px solid green;">
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle" style="left:0;">ALARME</div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Etat</div>
        <div class="green led">OK</div>
        <div class="red led">KO</div>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">ALARME1Alm</div>
        <canvas id="pieChartAlm" ></canvas>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Tickets1Alm</div>
        <canvas id="pieChartTkt" ></canvas>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContent">put here content</div>
     </div>
    </div>
     
    <div style="border: 1px solid red;">
     <input id="Dash_map_sumSlideAlarme" class="clsDashMap_sumSlideInput" type="radio" name="slides" checked>   
     <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Site " style="width: 50%;border: 2px solid black;">
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle">TECHNICIEN</div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Etat</div>
        <div class="green led">OK</div>
        <div class="red led">KO</div>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Alarmes2Tech</div>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Tickets2Tech</div>       
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContent">put here content</div>
     </div>
      <div class="Dash_map_sumSlide slide_Alarme" style="width: 50%;border: 2px solid darkturquoise;">
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideTitle" style="position: initial;">ACTION</div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideSiteContentSummary">
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Etat</div>
        <div class="green led">OK</div>
        <div class="red led">KO</div>
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">alarme3Act</div>       
       </div>
       <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBox">
        <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContentBoxTitle">Tickets3Act</div>       
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clsDashMap_sumSlideContent">put here content</div>
     </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
    
    <div class="Dash_map_wrapSliderchoise">
     <label for="Dash_map_sumSlideSite">Site / Alarme</label>
     <label for="Dash_map_sumSlideAlarme">Technicien / Action</label>
          <span id="autoplay" style="color:#fff;">Start</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank's for your help.... in the console it gives me this curent slide0
curent slide1, curent slide2,  curent slide3, curent slide4,  curent slide5,,  curent slide6.....knowing that i have only 2 slides....the second issue is that the slider doesn't move once i click the chekbox @H77

Comment: I've added the snippet above (from your pen). Does the same happen to you here?

Comment: yes now it does the same thing to me in codepen but not in my real web page...it moves once then i only get blank slides which is really weird because it's the same code...Do you think the rest of my code can affect it ??

Comment: maybe you have other element that start with the id "Dash". You could be more specific in the query selector. e.g. #Dash_map_wrapSlider input[id^="Dash"]

Comment: thank you very much for your help it works i had to add a loop as you did...now i have to  make it a stop/start button by adding a clearInterval, if i block , could you give me some help ?

Comment: H77 didn't expect u'll do it ..it works ..i really appreciate your help :)